# Need to replace innerText with images for noughts and crosses

Tags: javascript, html, css

Instead of showing 'O' or 'X' in my noughts and crosses grid, I need it to show images of noughts and crosses. The innerText in the JavaScript allows it to do this, but I want to replace this so it shows my png files in the grid. How can I do this?

This is for my homework at college, my tutor has set us a task of changing the text to images inside the grid but I am stuck. I tried changing it to 'innerHTML' and using img src but I feel like I am missing something.

```
var currentPlayer = "O";
var won = false;

alert("Welcome to the game!")

function place(box) {
    if(box.innerText != "" || won) return;
    box.innerText = currentPlayer;
    currentPlayer == "O" ? currentPlayer = "X" : currentPlayer = "O";
    checkGameBoard();       
}

function checkGameBoard() {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        checkWinner(document.getElementById(i + "_0").innerText,
        document.getElementById(i + "_1").innerText,
        document.getElementById(i + "_2").innerText);
    checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_" + i).innerText,
        document.getElementById("1_" + i).innerText,
        document.getElementById("2_" + i).innerText);
 }
 checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_0").innerText,
       document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
       document.getElementById("2_2").innerText);
 checkWinner(document.getElementById("0_2").innerText,
       document.getElementById("1_1").innerText,
       document.getElementById("2_0").innerText);
 }

function checkWinner(first, second, third) {
    if(first != "" && first == second && first == third) {
        alert("Winner! Well done!");
        won = true;
 }

}
```

Instead of 'X' and 'O' in the grid I'm expecting png images inside these.

Comment: document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
elem.src= "url Image"

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create an img html tag and append it to to the DOM as following

```js
const image = document.createElement("img").src = "your image source";
box.innerHTML = ""; // remove any text from the box
box.append(image); // add the image inside of your element
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this as an example :

```js
var img = new Image(100,100);  // (width = 100, height = 100)  are optional 
img.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSxjnfF8reo6uB7p6b98J0eEsJvbRtumlTtKcV_6qfxHm58O5ApnQ';
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.appendChild(img);
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```